Problem with Focus Shifting in TV Text Fields
I'm having trouble with the text fields on my TV. When I try to enter my email, password, and then click the button, the focus jumps around unexpectedly. It seems like the keyboard is automatically appearing and focusing on the button when I press keys. I've tried everything I can think of, but the focus is still not working correctly.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:searchrtv/widgets/customTextFormField.dart';
import 'package:searchrtv/widgets/custombtn.dart';

class Login extends StatelessWidget {
  Login({super.key});

  final TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  final Rx<bool> isObscure = true.obs;
  final loginFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();
  FocusNode? emailFocusNode;
  FocusNode? passwordFocusNode;
  FocusNode? btnFocusNode;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    emailFocusNode = FocusNode(
      onKey: (node, event) {
        node.unfocus();

        if (event.isKeyPressed(LogicalKeyboardKey.arrowUp)) {
          emailFocusNode!.unfocus();

          btnFocusNode!.requestFocus();

          return KeyEventResult.handled;
        } else if (event.isKeyPressed(LogicalKeyboardKey.arrowDown)) {
          emailFocusNode!.unfocus();

          passwordFocusNode!.requestFocus();

          return KeyEventResult.handled;
        }

        return KeyEventResult.ignored;
      },
    );

    passwordFocusNode = FocusNode(
      onKey: (node, event) {
        if (event.isKeyPressed(LogicalKeyboardKey.arrowUp)) {
          passwordFocusNode!.unfocus();

          emailFocusNode!.requestFocus();

          return KeyEventResult.handled;
        } else if (event.isKeyPressed(LogicalKeyboardKey.arrowDown)) {
          passwordFocusNode!.unfocus();

          btnFocusNode!.requestFocus();

          return KeyEventResult.handled;
        }

        return KeyEventResult.ignored;
      },
    );

    btnFocusNode = FocusNode(
      onKey: (node, event) {
        if (event.isKeyPressed(LogicalKeyboardKey.arrowUp)) {
          btnFocusNode!.unfocus();

          passwordFocusNode!.requestFocus();

          return KeyEventResult.handled;
        } else if (event.isKeyPressed(LogicalKeyboardKey.arrowDown)) {
          btnFocusNode!.unfocus();

          emailFocusNode!.requestFocus();

          return KeyEventResult.handled;
        }

        return KeyEventResult.ignored;
      },
    );

    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: size.height * 1,
        width: size.width * 1,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
              width: size.width * 0.4,
              height: size.height * 0.5,
              color: Colors.grey[900],
              child: Form(
                key: loginFormKey,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    const SizedBox(height: 10),
                    const Center(
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.remove_red_eye_rounded,
                        size: 64,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const Text(
                      'Searchr.Tv',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 25.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 10),
                    customTextFormField(
                      focusNode: emailFocusNode,
                      labelText: 'Email',
                      hintText: 'Email Address',
                      prefixIconData: Icons.email,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                      textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                      validator: (value) {
                        return null;
                      },
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                    customTextFormField(
                      focusNode: passwordFocusNode,
                      labelText: 'Password',
                      hintText: "****",
                      prefixIconData: Icons.vpn_key_rounded,
                      textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                      validator: (value) {
                        return null;
                      },
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 6.0),
                    CustomButton(
                      focusNode: btnFocusNode,
                      text: 'Login',
                      onPressed: () async {},
                      hasInfiniteWidth: true,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const Divider(
              height: 200,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
            const SizedBox(width: 10),
            Container(
              width: size.width * 0.4,
              height: size.height * 0.4,
              color: Colors.green,
              child: const Text("data"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

